# Detect a server supporting SPDY?

Tags: tls, web-application, attack-prevention, compression, spdy

With my current interest in the CRIME attack, I am currently trying to check if there actually exits a way to "fingerprint" a server that supports SPDY?

My research lead me to believe only that the response header "X-Firefox-SPDY" can help. Is there another way?

Comment: Do you have malicious intent?

Comment: Nope. None what so ever. My question stemmed from the fact that I could only detect SPDY existence on Twitter, GMail, etc. by means of the response header. So I wanted to know if you have a way to detect it. That is all.

Comment: Try to connect to it using SPDY protocol, one would soon find out if there is SPDY there or not...

Answer (score 5):

The answer to your question would depend on the context in which you're interested.

If you're interested in detecting SPDY servers while browsing the web you'll first need a browser that supports SPDY (e.g. Firefox 11+ or Chrome). In this scenario the best way to detect SPDY is browser dependant.

For Chrome there are a couple of ways:

- You can browse to `chrome://net-internals/#spdy` for a list of all currently open SPDY connections (because SPDY connections are persistent - every tab that contains a document from a server which supports SPDY should be present).
- If you're interested only in the current tab you might examine the `window.chrome.loadTimes().wasFetchedViaSpdy` DOM property.

For Firefox, the only way I'm aware of is to look for the presence of `X-Firefox-Spdy` response header. Do note that for this to work, you must enable SPDY support (it is on by default as of Firefox 13, otherwise - set `network.http.spdy.enabled` to `true`.

All this depends on using a SPDY enabled browser, and manually checking servers. If you'll want to automate this, use a browser that doesn't support SPDY, or just plainly skip the browser - you'll need another strategy. As I see you have two options in this case:

- SPDY servers can be configured to advertise their support of SPDY when sending HTTP responses. This would require you to inspect the presence of the appropriate `Alternative-Protocol` headers ([outlined in the SPDY draft](http://www.chromium.org/spdy/spdy-protocol/spdy-protocol-draft2#TOC-Deployment)).
- Simply establish a TCP connection to the server an send it a SETTIGNS (HELLO) or a SYN_STREAM frame and see if it responds according to the [SPDY protocol](http://www.chromium.org/spdy/spdy-protocol/spdy-protocol-draft3).